# Properties of area of simple polygon with integer coordinates

Tags: area, polygons

Is the area of a simple polygon with integer coordinates is half an integer? I was reading shoelace formula and this occurred to me.

Comment: Intuitively, one can explain this in terms of oblique lines forming straight-edge triangles with integer perpendicular sides, rather than a full rectangle.

Answer (score 2):

Might be the  long way around this. But as a corollary to [Pick's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick's_theorem) which states that

$$A=i+\frac{b}{2}-1$$

where $i$ it the number of integer coordinates inside the polygon and $b$ is the number of integer coordinates on the boundary of the polygon. Because $i$ and $b$ are integers, you have $A$ in the integers or half-integers.

---

And as you suggested as a result of the [Shoelace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula) which states that

$$A= {1 \over 2}|x_1y_2 + x_2y_3 + \cdots + x_{n-1}y_n + x_ny_1 - x_2y_1 - x_3y_2 - \cdots - x_ny_{n-1} - x_1y_n|$$

If $x_i,y_i\in\mathbb{Z}$ then the absolute value is an integer (because the sum, difference and product of integers is still an integer). And the $1/2$ our front leaves us with the integers or half-integers.

---

A third approach would be to prove that any lattice triangle (a triangle with only integer coordinates) has an integer or half-integer area (hint: draw a bounding rectangle). Then show that any lattice polygon can be partitioned into non-overlapping lattice triangles.